# apache2.conf file

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, configuration, authentication

I am trying to use the Mod_auth_form to control access and permissions of web files/pages

But I am facing some problems I think with the apache2.conf or in my case (virtual host file.conf)
I am following such approach:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/www/testfolder">
AuthFormProvider file
AuthType form
AuthName "Reserved Area"
Session On
SessionCookieName session path=/
require valid-user

# This is the login page
ErrorDocument 401 /login.html

# This is the file containing users login data
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/auth/.htpasswd
```

But I dont really understand the logic and how it works can anybody simplify it for me

I want Login.html to be accessible to every body
But other pages/files only to those signed in users

That is all I need.

Comment: Is this the same problem you asked about yesterday? https://askubuntu.com/q/1424392/243321

Comment: Voting to close because you asked this before and because you're better off asking on StackOverflow or places dedicated to Apache httpd. Note also that on Ubuntu, web content would be in `/var/www/html`, not in `/usr/local/apache2/www`, nor should you be editing `apache2.conf`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mod\_auth\_form apache2 is not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424392/mod-auth-form-apache2-is-not-working)